# When I access a list on an object it incorrectly returns as empty list

Tags: python, list, class

I am writing a code for a computational physics project.

I'd like to know how I can implement a class in python by adding an array to the instances of the class.

Here is my original part of code:

```
class Particle():
    def __init__(self, (x,y,z), n, radius, neighbours):

         self.n = n
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.z = z
         self.radius = radius




number  = loadtxt("final_limited.txt", usecols=(0,), unpack=True, dtype = int)
c1,c2,c3,r = loadtxt("final_limited.txt", usecols=(1,2,3,5), unpack=True, dtype=float)





number_of_particles = len(number)
my_particles        = []
overlap             = []
contact_number      = []




for i in range(number_of_particles):
    n = number[i]
    x = c1[i]
    y = c2[i]
    z = c3[i]
    radius = r[i]
    neighbours = []

    particle = Particle((x,y,z), n, radius, neighbours)
    my_particles.append(particle)


for particle1 in my_particles:
    count = 0
    for particle2 in my_particles:
        distance = PBCdist(particle1, particle2)
        sum_of_radii = Sum_radii(particle1, particle2)
        if (distance < sum_of_radii) and (distance>0):
            count +=1

            olap = (Decimal(sum_of_radii) - Decimal(distance))
            overlap.append(olap)
    contact_number.append(count)
```

I would like to do the following:

```
class Particle():
    def __init__(self, (x,y,z), n, radius, neighbours):
        neighbours = []
        self.n = n
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.radius = radius
        self.neighbours = neighbours
```

And then, in the nested loop:

```
for particle1 in my_particles:
    count = 0
    for particle2 in my_particles:
        distance = PBCdist(particle1, particle2)
        sum_of_radii = Sum_radii(particle1, particle2)
        if (distance < sum_of_radii) and (distance>0):
             count +=1
             neighbours.append(particle2.n)
             olap = (Decimal(sum_of_radii) - Decimal(distance))
             overlap.append(olap)
    contact_number.append(count)
```

As you can see, I'd like to give associate to each particle the list of its neighbours as a property of each element of the class.

However, when I check it this code does not work. I'd like tp be able to say type:

```
print my_particles[0].neighbours
```

And obtain the list.

Moreover, do you know if there is a Numpy dtype like float that can give me the required 20-21 decimal places? Using float data type my code is of course faster(10 times), but i'd like to use a numpy type that allows full precision required, rather than Decimal.

Answer (score 2):

You replace the neighbours parameter with an empty list

```
def __init__(self, (x,y,z), n, radius, neighbours):
     neighbours = []  # <- HERE
     self.neighbours = neighbours
```

Remove that line, and you should be able to access the neighbour list.

Comment: Yeah, that line struck me as peculiar also.

Comment: Possibly that was supposed to be the "default to `None`, use empty list if it is the default" trick?